# This error keeps returning, using the Provider class: Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, class, dart, provider

```
Error: Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>.
This is likely a mistake and is therefore
unsupported.

If you want to expose a variable that can be anything, consider changing
`dynamic` to `Object` instead.
'package:provider/src/provider.dart':
Failed assertion: line 307 pos 7: 'T != dynamic'
```

what does chanfing it from dynamic to object mean?

Code:

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        FutureBuilder(
          future: Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUser(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return displayUserInformation(context, snapshot);
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type that will return the static method `Provider.of<T>(context)`.

Dynamic is not an option here ;-)

The example given in the Flutter documentation is self explanatory

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CartModel(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),

....

Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false).removeAll();
```